# How to pass an integer using g_signal_connect

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I'm trying to pass an integer using g_signal_connect into my function to display the button index but it throws an error:

```
gui.c:35:39: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
       G_CALLBACK(button_clicked), (gpointer)row+column);
                                   ^
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gsignal.h:475:73: note: in definition of macro ‘g_signal_connect’
 g_signal_connect_data ((instance), (detailed_signal), (c_handler), (data), NULL, (GConnectFlags) 0)
                                                                     ^~~~
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void button_clicked(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data) {
  g_print("Button %p clicked\n", data);
  gtk_button_set_label (GTK_BUTTON (widget), "X");
}

#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *fixed;

  gchar *values[9] = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
  GtkWidget *button[9];

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "GtkFixed");
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 300, 200);
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

  fixed = gtk_fixed_new();
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), fixed);

  for (int row = 0; row < 9; row+=3){
    for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++){

      button[row+column] = gtk_button_new_with_label(values[row+column]);
      gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), button[row+column], column*70, row*30);
      gtk_widget_set_size_request(button[row+column], 50, 50);
      g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button[row+column]), "clicked",
          G_CALLBACK(button_clicked), (gpointer)row+column);

    }
  }

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
      G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

I've tried using gint instead of int for row and column but that doesn't seem to change anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This `(gpointer)row+column` doesn't look right - you're casting `row` but not `column`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the expression `(gpointer)row+column` is equal to `((gpointer)row)+column`, which is equal to `&((gpointer)row)[column]`. This is probably not what you expect.

Secondly, the compiler most likely not be able to see that neither `row` nor `column` will never be negative. This could lead to it generating bad code. Use `unsigned` as the type for `row` and `column` instead.

And finally for "fixing" your warning: `int` is typically 32 bits, while it seems that pointers on your system is larger than that (probably 64 if you're on a 64-bit system). You need to temporarily convert to a type that is compatible with both integers and pointers.

Putting all together the expression should look something like

```
(gpointer)(uintptr_t)(row+column)
```

Then in the callback you need to do the opposite casting:

```
unsigned row_col = (unsigned)(uintptr_t)data;
```

Comment: There are macros `GPOINTER_TO_UINT()` and `GUINT_TO_POINTER()` available in GTK that do this same thing a bit more concisely, in case you would like that.